# How to check if iPhone address bar is showing

Tags: jquery, html, ios, iphone

We are using the following routine to scroll from a fixed horizontal navigation bar to a particular point on the screen.

The routine requires an OFFSET to prevent the section we are scrolling to from disappearing behind the fixed horizontal navigation bar which has a height of 50px:

```
$('.scroll1')
.on('click touch',
    function(){
    var offset = ($(window).height()/2)-50;
    $('#kapitel1').animatedScroll({duration: 3000, easing: 'easeOutExpo'},{left: 0, top: offset});
})
```

This works fine, with one exception: we need TWO different OFFSET values for the iPhone depending on whether the address bar is showing or not.

Most solutions to this problem rely on hiding the iPhone address bar completely. A common method seems to be:

window.scrollTo(0, 0)

However, when the user scrolls back to the top of the screen the address bar - of course - reappears.

We need a solution which detects whether the address bar is currently showing or not. We were thinking detecting the height of the screen might help:

```
if(($(window).height()>??px){
    var offset = ($(window).height()/2)-50;
}else{
    var offset = ($(window).height()/2)+10; //account for 60px address bar
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Any ideas on how we can simply and reliably detect if the address bar is currently showing or not?

Many thanks in advance for any help!